# intelliJ idea 10 community edition and GWT plugin

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

Having hard time installing GWT plugin. Tried to search for GWT plugins and all I was able to find was GWT Imagebundle which is pretty outdated. Tried File Menu -> configure plugins but didn't help as the plugin is not installed yet.

Is there a support for GWT plugin in intelliJ 10 community edition? If there is can some one please point me to the right document to install it? Just to make sure, I installed scala plugin and I am able to see it in "Add modules" section.

This is my first time using intellij and I love it so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [no GWT support](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) in the Community Edition.

Comment: Looks like it can be accomplished even though the app does not natively support it.  - http://java.dzone.com/tips/gwt-development-intellij-idea

Comment: also see: http://www.urbancat.org/2010/06/how-i-use-intellij-community-edition.html

Comment: I dont know about you guys but I DO work with Intellij Community Edition and GWT. There are several pluggins that work and what I really like is [GWT-Platform (GWTP)](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7318?pr=idea)

Comment: @kostia and which plugs are those? The urbancat link above doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from the version 11 it's not possible to add PROJECT_FOLDER/src as it was described in the previously posted (by ctorx) link http://java.dzone.com/tips/gwt-development-intellij-idea. Once we add a source folder it appears as an "Empty library" and doesn't work. This is because IDEA treats it as a folder where should be compiled classes not sources.

But there is a workaround. To fix it we have to hack the module's IML file. Find the following lines in the IML file of your entry point module

```
<orderEntry type="module-library">
  <library>
    <CLASSES />
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES>
      <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" />
    </SOURCES>
  </library>
</orderEntry>
```

and move your path into the `CLASSES` tag, so the entire thing looks like the following

```
<orderEntry type="module-library">
  <library>
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES />
  </library>
</orderEntry>
```