# Setting up libgdx in IntelliJ Idea with GWT Support?

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea, libgdx

So far the documentation doesn't include the set up of GWT project in IDEA, and my limited google skill can't find the solution. Is it possible?

Comment: dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774115/intellij-idea-10-community-edition-and-gwt-plugin?rq=1

Comment: No, I can setup GWT just fine (I use ultimate edition) but the problem is with setup GWT with libgdx in idea.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/IntelliJIDEALibgdx

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/gwt.html

 this should help u

Comment: no, I have tried them both.

Comment: You will have to be more specific about your problem.  Is it the GWT code you're having problems with?  The XML configuration?  Is there some part of the Eclipse-based GWT-setup doc that you don't know how to translate into IDEA?

Comment: I can't convert `libgdx` html5 project from eclipse to idea, and when I try creating new new module in idea it didn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

If you generated your libgdx project using the `gdx-setup.jar` file, then you should import your project by using the following link: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA

HTML: `View -> Tool Window -> Terminal`, in the terminal, make sure you are in the root folder of your project. Then execute `gradlew.bat html:superDev` (Windows) or `./gradlew html:superDev` (Linux, Mac OS X). This will take a while, as your Java code is compiled to Javascript.

Once you see the message The code server is ready, fire up your browser and go to `http://localhost:8080/html`. This is your app running in the browser! When you change any of your Java code or assets, just click the SuperDev refresh button while you are on the site and the server will recompile your code and reload the page! To kill the process, simply press CTRL + C in the terminal window.

Once this bug in the `Gradle tooling API` is fixed, we can simplify running the HTML5 by using the Gradle integration. At the moment, the Gradle process will run forever even if canceled.

Also just a heads up, after you have run the gradle command it might say something like this:

> The code server is ready.
> Next, visit: `http://localhost:9876/`
>
> Building 91% > :html:superDev

Even though it says 91%, don't worry it will still work, just go here to run it: `http://localhost:8080/html/`, NOT the url mentioned in the log.

Also to deploy you need to run `./gradlew html:dist` to generate production code, you want to copy everything inside `./html/build/dist/` to your server. Running that command produces the code in that directory. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/82588/54396

Comment: This question predates the `gdx-setup.jar` but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make GWT work with libgdx simply by:

- downloading (http://www.gwtproject.org/download.html) the GWT SDK,
- extracting it,
- then in the project structure -> `project-name-html` -> dependencies,
- just press the + and add the extracted GWT directory
- A dialog appears and I just unticked all the samples

The "Dependencies Storage Format" needed to be "Intellij IDEA", not Eclipse for this to work for me.